# Why does QPainter restore cause segmentfault?

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qpainter

My program  sometimes(low probability) crashed with the following imformation backtrace:

```
Error: signal 11:
/ri/flamingo_console(_Z7handleri+0x174)[0x884a14]
/lib/libc.so.6(__default_sa_restorer_v2+0x0)[0xb5d3de60]
/lib/libc.so.6(memcpy+0x74)[0xb5d94124]
/ri/Qt5.5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN7QString11reallocDataEjb+0x8c) 
[0xb60f2f68]
/ri/Qt5.5/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5(+0x2f2284)[0xb6923284]  
/ri/flamingo_console[0x5f75a8]
/ri/flamingo_console[0x54f6e4]
```

I use the tool of addr2line and find the text address of 0x5f75a8 is in the following function:

```
void RElementStyle::drawText( QPainter &painter,
           const QRect &rect,
           const QString &str,
           Qt::AlignmentFlag align )
{
    painter.save();
    painter.setPen( mCommon.getColor( mStatus, str) );
    //! font
    QFont font = qApp->font();
    font.setPointSize( mCommon.mContentFont.mSize );
    painter.setFont( font );
    painter.drawText( rect,
                  align | Qt::AlignVCenter,
                  str );
    painter.restore();  //! this is the crash line 0x54f6e4
}
```

I learn some things about painter.restore(), and I konw the restore() pops the settings of painter.However, I can't understand why the restore can cause a segment fault. Can someone analyze it for me? Thanks very much.

Comment: change `QPainter &painter` to  `QPainter *painter`

Comment: @eyllanesc    Thanks and I will try it. And Can you explain some details？

Comment: @eyllanesc, that should make no difference. If you think otherwise, you should probably explain *why.* fengfenglin, is there a chance you have another thread able to access/change `painter` concurrently? That may well cause an issue.

Comment: Then the cause is another, if the asker do not provide a [mcve] I would be speculating, I think the error is generated by another part of the code.

Comment: @paxdiablo In general QPainter should not be accessed from another thread simultaneously.